# Lines in my code being skipped and I am not sure why

Tags: python-2.7

I am using python 2.7 and I am pretty new to python. I was wanted to ask why lines in my code are being skipped although I don't see a reason for them to be.

My code is seen below:

```
def add_client:
    code for adding client

def check_clients:
    code for listing out client info

modes = {'add': add_client, 'check': check_clients}        
while True:
    while True:
        action = raw_input('Input Action: \n').lower()
        if action in modes or ['exit']:
            break
        print 'Actions available:',
        for i in modes:
            print i.title() + ',',
        print 'Exit' 

    if action in modes:
        modes[mode](wb)

    if action == 'exit':
        break
```

When I run the code and input an action that is not in the list of modes, it does not print out 'Actions available: add, check, exit' and just seems to skip like seen below.

```
Input Action:
k
Input Action:
```

If I change the code to what is seen below it works as intended:

```
modes = {'add': add_entries, 'check': check_stats}        
while True:
    while True:
        mode = raw_input('Input Action: \n').lower()
        if mode not in modes:
            print 'Actions available:',
            for i in modes:
                print i.title() + ',',
            print 'End/Exit' 
        if mode in modes or ['end', 'exit']:
            break

    if mode in modes:
        modes[mode](wb)

    if mode in ['end', 'exit']:
        break
```

Output:

```
Input Action:
k
Actions available: Add, Check, End/Exit
```

From my understanding, I thought that when an if statement is false, the code within the if statement is skipped and the code following should be ran, but for some reason, this doesn't seem to be the case here. Is there a reason for this or is my understanding of the if statement incorrect?

Comment: try with `action in modes or action=='exit'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition `action in modes or ['exit']` evaluates to `True` regardless of the value of `action`. It read like `(action in modes) or (['exit'])` (so you apply `or` operator to operands `action in modes` and `['exit']`). Non-empty list `['exit']` evaluates to `True` in boolean context, so `or` returns `True`. You are suggested to use `action in modes or action == 'exit'` here to achieve your goal.

Comment: `modes` is a dictionary, not an list